# Rails Upgrade 3.2.13 to rails 4.2.1 Form not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In my app Form contain message draft, send message, Schedule message functions are not working properly after upgraded my rails app 3.2.13 to 4.2.1

If I make a draft message from my form it will be showing this code in my server:

```
Processing by HomeController#share_message as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "given"=>"draft", "cap"=>["8241044"], "@image"=>{"title"=>"Testing", "desc"=>"hi tester..", "avatar"=>""}, "commit"=>"Shorten url", "date"=>"", "hour"=>"04", "minute"=>"00", "meridian"=>"PM", "time"=>"04:00 PM"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  ServicesTwitter Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `services_twitters`.* FROM `services_twitters` WHERE `services_twitters`.`uid` = '8241044' AND `services_twitters`.`provider` = 'twitter'  ORDER BY `services_twitters`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  CompanyPage Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `company_pages`.* FROM `company_pages` WHERE `company_pages`.`fb_company_id` = '8241044' AND `company_pages`.`provider` = 'facebook'  ORDER BY `company_pages`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  CompanyPage Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `company_pages`.* FROM `company_pages` WHERE `company_pages`.`fb_company_id` = '8241044' AND `company_pages`.`provider` = 'linkedin'  ORDER BY `company_pages`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `service_schedules` (`service_id`, `provider`, `token`, `secret`, `uid`, `desc`, `fb_company_id`, `if_draft`, `title`, `is_group`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (11, 'linkedin', '4eb93d8f-40f6-4d1e-af66-58b2fefae283', '7528bd42-5cf1-4afc-9adf-33cd29d54167', '8241044', 'hi tester..', '8241044', 1, 'Testing', 1, '2015-06-12 10:33:30', '2015-06-12 10:33:30')
   (94.9ms)  COMMIT
```

If I check in my Draft option I won't get my saved drafted data.But server code will be working fine:

```
Started GET "/share/drafts?clientID=1&userID=1&type=admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-12 16:09:03 +0530
Processing by HomeController#list_of_drafts as */*
  Parameters: {"clientID"=>"1", "userID"=>"1", "type"=>"admin"}
  ServiceSchedule Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `service_schedules`.* FROM `service_schedules` WHERE `service_schedules`.`client_id` = 1 AND `service_schedules`.`if_draft` = 1  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Rendered home/_list_of_drafts.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered home/list_of_drafts.js.erb (8.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 17.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/share/drafts?clientID=1&lead=1&post=1&type=admin&userID=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-12 16:09:03 +0530
Processing by HomeController#list_of_drafts as JS
  Parameters: {"clientID"=>"1", "lead"=>"1", "post"=>"1", "type"=>"admin", "userID"=>"1"}
  ServiceSchedule Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `service_schedules`.* FROM `service_schedules` WHERE `service_schedules`.`client_id` = 1 AND `service_schedules`.`if_draft` = 1  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Rendered home/_list_of_drafts.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered home/list_of_drafts.js.erb (10.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 19.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

I think my code are working fine but why I didn't get my draft data? After upgrade only I get this problem.

This my draft router `match "share/drafts" =>"home#list_of_drafts", :as =>:draft, :via => [:get,:post]`

That same problem in my send message, schedule message options. Can you help me please?  Thank you

```
15/06/2015(today)
```

Hi all, again I have some issue for Draft message function.Now I can view draft message But I can't edit draft message it just displaying empty page and saved Draft time also Displaying wrong time. Can you tell me any suggestions please??

Comment: **Just a tip :** You can pass form authenticity token as `= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token`, to get rid of **Can't verify CSRF token authenticity**

Comment: I've no Idea about that How to do and where to do that?@Abhi

Comment: Do you have `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in the `ApplicationController`?  If so, this should automatically add the authenticity token to your forms.  See [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) for more information.

Comment: Hi Steve, Now I'm getting this error:      Processing by HomeController#share_message as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "given"=>"draft", "cap"=>["8241044", "1588582243"], "@image"=>{"title"=>"Testing", "desc"=>"Testing good", "avatar"=>""}, "commit"=>"Shorten url", "date"=>"", "hour"=>"06", "minute"=>"40", "meridian"=>"PM", "time"=>"06:40 PM"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):

Comment: But if i comment '#protect_from_forgery ' i'm getting draft messages I won't get others

Comment: @Pal, you have to write down "protect_from_forgery" in your Application controller without this you can not come outside from errors. After this what exactly error is coming please write down that and also write down the form view and controller if possible.

Comment: I just added protect_from_forgery method after this line skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token I referred this linkhttp://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html#method-i-form_authenticity_token

Comment: Now working fine draft message function. thank you @Chitra

Comment: Up vote please if information was helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry don't have REPUTATION to vote Thank for your vote@Chitra

Answer (score 1):

I just added `protect_from_forgery` method to
 `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` 
I referred this link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection‌​.html#method-i-form_authenticity_token

Thank you guys